# How to apply a texture preserving the lightning of the original

Tags: texture, lighting-effects

I already saw some tutorial how to add a texture to the picture (for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnB2NUIb1h0).

I am interested in similar technique but with one extra condition -- preserving the lighting. Let's say you have a house in the picture -- let's focus on its wall -- its entire area is not equally lit, and what worse some obstacles can shadow some parts (for example roof can cast a shadow at the top of the wall).

When I add new texture to the wall it will be obvious there is something wrong with the picture, because lighting would not match -- thus this condition of preserving the lighting.

*I have Gimp installed, but any program will suffice, because I am more interested in current state of the capabilities of this feature, less in day-to-day usage of it (thus I can install a trial version of necessary program).*

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that adding a texture will affect the image in some way. 
It also depends on what type of texture you want to use.

But there are 2 methods you can try. Either set a high contrast texture where most of the values are white on multiply or use overlay for a texture where most of the values are a middle gray.

Do you need further explanation? ;) It's maybe kind of hard to understand if you don't know what the blend modes do...

Comment: Thank you, but when blending two textures the original pattern comes into play. Take for example "#" -- this is just a pattern, but when you treat it is as source of lightning information you will get darker and lighter places in the outcome.